# Excel VBA choose cells to print - Set Print Area

Tags: vba, excel

I want to choose the print area using VBA and print them out.

I have tried this method, but it gives me an error

> This formula is missing a range reference or a defined name

```
Worksheets("Printable Version").Activate
With Sheets("Printable Version")
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1").Value & ":" & .Range("G55").Value
End With
```

Comment: .Range("A1").Value  should be .Range("A1").address?

Comment: Are you trying to set the print range to A1:G55 or do you have the ranges in those cells?

Comment: If you are trying to set it to that range then simply `...= Range("A1:G55")`

Comment: I just want to simply set the area to print out

Comment: @ScottCraner : you're missing a point!^^ `PrintArea = .Range("A1:G55")` ;)

Comment: Worksheets("Printable Version").Activate
 With Sheets("Printable Version")
        ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1:G55")
  End With                  is this correct?

Comment: @BarryWang : exactly! ;)

Comment: @R3uK true, but as the OP activated the sheet it shouldn't matter. 8P But it should be there.

Comment: @ScottCraner : Hehe, indeed! So I missed a point too! ;)

Comment: @R3uK  Hi it shows "Unable to set the PrintArea property of the PageSetup class"...

Comment: Add `.Address` to the end of `.Range("A1:G55")`  it expects a address string not an actual range, so @Lowpar suggestion would have worked also.  So `ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1:G55").Address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out bu using this piece of code:

```
WorkSheet("sheetname").range("A1:G55").printout
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With Sheets("Printable Version")
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = .Range("A1:G55").Address
    '''Or
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:G55"
    .PrintOut
End With
```